# In Idris, why do we need to ascribe the kind to type parameters when they have already been defined elsewhere?

Tags: idris

Why do we write `f : Type -> Type` instead of just `f` below - is it not inferred from `Functor f`?:

```
interface Functor f => Applicative (f : Type -> Type) where
    pure  : a -> f a
    (<*>) : f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`f` has already had its kind (or should I just say Type in Idris) defined in:

```
interface Functor (f : Type -> Type) where
    map : (m : a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I have heard that there are many situations that Idris cannot infer types where Haskell would due to Idris's dependent type system. Is this one such situation?

A related question, [Failed to declare MonadPlus interface constrained on Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206752/failed-to-declare-monadplus-interface-constrained-on-monad), describes the same behavior, but doesn't really address why the type can't be inferred.

Comment: i believe this is [also the case in idris 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63206752/5986907)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to declare MonadPlus interface constrained on Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206752/failed-to-declare-monadplus-interface-constrained-on-monad)

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher it's possible the OP wants to know _why_ this is the case, and why it doesn't default to `Type` only when there's no other information

Comment: That is the same behavior, but it would be good to know why it's the case, and if it is something that might be changed later (vs being a fundamental constraint of the type system).

Comment: To reiterate, I'm curious about why the type is not inferred - the linked answer, while informative, doesn't seem to speak to this.